# Training LUIS to predict entities without Phrase List

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I am trying to train LUIS to recognize entity through few utterances. I initially tried to train with few utterances with different entity values. The entity values are made up of two words or more. For example, 'customer engagement', 'empower your teams' etc.
I am not able to get LUIS to identify the entity correctly because of the variation in the number of words.

I cannot use Phrase List as the values as the values are dynamic.

How can I get train LUIS to recognize the multiple words in the utterance and identify the entity effectively?

Comment: Please make sure you follow the authoring cycle guidelines (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-app-iteration). Include your app definition, example utterances, and endpoint query results, if you want more help.

Answer (score 0):

This still requires you to provide some training data in the form of canonical values and synonyms, but another way to approach this would be to use a [list entity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/add-entities#add-list-entities) inside of a composite entity.  Other than this, you'll currently have to provide a larger amounts of training data/phrase list data as LUIS doesn't look at the definition of a word.